# Requirements for completing Star Trek Armada Dark Omens mission?

Tags: star-trek-armada

I've got a big fleet built up, have researched everything available, and have wiped all the Borg off the map.  The Borg starbases are gone, which is what it claims the mission objective is.  However, the mission doesn't register as complete.  Of note, there's a tiny green dot on the overview.  If I fly a ship down there, there's nothing.  If I fly my ships away and the board grays out, there's a small gray box with illegible red text that appears in that location.  I presume I'm supposed to do something with this?

Running on Windows XP platform.

Answer (score 2):

Running on Windows 10 platform.  I replayed the mission. I flew my extra ships (ships that I built for the mission) to the shipyards and decommissioned them to reclaim the resources.  Then I left the Enterprise in range of the very last Borg target: their dilithium collector.  When I had the Enterprise destroy the ship, then the cutscene came on and the mission was finished.

Link to animated gif showing the process: https://gifyu.com/image/GLiD

I don't recommend using the cheat to skip the mission since it creates substantial glitches in the game: too many to count.